# How do I select Locales in the "raspi-config"

Tags: raspi-config

I am trying to generate locales with raspi-config

I can't figure out how to tick the box on this interface.

Return, tab, right arrow... they all move the cursor, or bring me to the next screen, but I can't figure out how to add an asterisk into the square brackets

[image]

```
Configuring locales
Locales are a framework to switch between multiple languages and allow users to use their language, country, characters, collation order, etc.

Please choose which locales to generate. UTF-8 locales should be chosen by default, particularly for new installations. Other character sets may be useful for backwards compatibility with
older systems and software.

Locales to be generated:
```

Here is the default one pre checked:
[image]

Comment: @SteveRobillard: Shouldn't this be an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight the desired item using the up and down arrows, then use the spacebar to select. Finally either Tab or Enter to complete the form.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try space bar! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If `raspi-config` is difficult and frustrating, there's an *easier way*!

1. Open the file `/etc/locale.gen` in your editor, and **un-comment** the locale you wish to use. For example:

   ```bsh
   sudo nano /etc/locale.gen
   ```

If you don't wish to use the default, you may remove it by **commenting** it; i.e. add the `#` symbol as the first character in the default line - just as most or all others are.

2. Run/re-run `locale-gen`; i.e. at the command line prompt of your shell:

   ```bsh
   $ sudo locale-gen
   ```

   fwiw, `locale-gen` is located in `/usr/sbin`, and included in the default PATH environment

Comment: "easier"?? in the old days I always found the traditional locale setting one of the most frustrating steps in setting up an OS

Comment: @Milliways Well, on the Pi it's just two commands on the command line, and that's all it takes :) So, _easy_ indeed, IMHO.